# Docker image does not appear as a service in openshift

Tags: docker, openshift

I want to deploy an application in Openshift directly from the Docker image.
The application itself uses a MongoDb database. I tried to adapt [the scenario from Openshift tutorial](https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/deploying-images/)

As a difference, I first added a MongoDb persistent storage in the project, then added the docker image for my application itself.

Problem is my application does not appear as a "service", hence I can not create a route to it and have no access to it...

What did I miss here?

Comment: What do you get when you run ``oc get all -o name``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems comes here from no port being exposed by the image.
You need to be sure your DockerFile as an  `EXPOSE` line somewhere.

Once this is added, openshift correctly creates a service for the image.